# How to collapse any gaps in sequence of integers in R?

Tags: r, sequence, rank, dense-rank

Is there a handy base R or package function for collapsing, or interpolating, between any gaps for the integer values of a sequence of numbers? I've searched functions like `dplyr::dense_rank` but they don't do the trick in this case. The below code generates an example starting sequence of numbers in a single column (column = `Grp`):

```
> myDF <- data.frame(Grp = c(1,2.1,2.2,4.1,4.2,6.1,9))
> myDF   
  Grp
1 1.0    
2 2.1    
3 2.2    
4 4.1
5 4.2
6 6.1
7 9.0
```

Here's how I would like to change the output; below I manually add values with a column to the right of each `Grp` row ("Collapse") explaining what I am trying to derive:

```
    > myDF   
      Grp    Collapse 
    1 1.0    Every sequence starts with 1 so leave Grp as is
    2 2.1    Integer gap between rows 1-2 is <= 1 so leave Grp as is
    3 2.2    Integer gap between rows 2-3 is <= 1 so leave Grp as is
    4 3.0    Integer gap between original rows 3-4 is not <= 1 so fill in the gap with the seq integer 
    5 4.1    Integer gap between rows 4-5 is <= 1 so leave Grp as is
    6 4.2    Integer gap between rows 5-6 is <= 1 so leave Grp as is
    7 5.0    Integer gap between original rows 5-6 is not <= 1 so fill in the gap with the seq integer 
    8 6.1    Integer gap between row 7-8 is <= 1 so leave Grp as is
    9 7.0    Integer gap between original rows 6-7 is not <= 1 so fill in the gap with the seq integer
   10 8.0    Integer gap between original rows 6-7 is not <= 1 so fill in the gap with the seq integer
   11 9.0    Integer gap between row 10-11 is <= 1 so leave Grp as is
```

Comment: Could you please clarify what output you hope to get? It is somewhat clear that you want to apply some conditional logic based on the lagged differences of values in the column Grp, but I have no clue what you mean by "fill in the gap with the seq integer".

Comment: Hi, the desired output is shown and explained at the bottom of the OP. Also, Maël provides the correct solution below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do:

```r
f <- floor(myDF$Grp)
s <- seq(min(f), max(f))
sort(c(myDF$Grp, s[!s %in% f]))
#[1] 1.0 2.1 2.2 3.0 4.1 4.2 5.0 6.1 7.0 8.0 9.0
```

Comment: Wow, that is exactly right. Short and concise too.

Comment: sort(union(myDF$Grp, s)) might be more readable imho.